# Stubbing Method that Throws Exception on Spied Object With Mockito (Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I've been surprised to have not been able to find an answer to this problem. I have a method that tries to read from a file, which potentially throws an IOException if the file can't be found:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
open fun readCurrentTemperature(): Int {
    FileInputStream(coreTemperatureFile).use { inputStream ->
        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
            //get the first line from the file
            return Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()) / CONVERT_MILLISECONDS_TO_SECONDS //The coreTemp file appears to be measured in millidegrees
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty simple. I'm trying to stub this method on a spied object. According to documentation with spied objects the real method is executed UNLESS it's stubbed. I did so with the following:

```
Mockito.doReturn(40).`when`(subject).readCurrentTemperature()
```

What I'm seeing is that the method is STILL being executed as it throws the IOException since the file doesn't exist in the environment that the test is running in. I have logic to handle that exception in the class I'm spying on but I want to test my logic that handles a correct value being returned. Any ideas as to why the method is still executing?

**EDIT**

For some more context, the logic I'm testing is in a RX chain:

```
bitService.bitEventStream
        .map {
            try {
                readCurrentTemperature()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // If exception is thrown return known error number
                IO_ERROR_DEFAULT_TEMPERATURE
            }
        }
```

The entire test looks like so:

```
 @Test
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun checkTemperatureNormal() {
    setMockSeat()
    Mockito.doReturn(40).`when`(subject).readCurrentTemperature()
    bridge.bitObserver.onNext(BitEvent.RunBit)
}
```

The bitObserver and the bitEventStream are the same PublishSubject. Here's a snippet from the setup method:

```
 bridge = Mockito.mock(BasicBitBridge::class.java)
    var publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<BitEvent>()
    Mockito.doReturn(publishSubject).`when`(bridge).bitEventStream
    Mockito.doReturn(publishSubject).`when`(bridge).bitObserver
    subject = Mockito.spy(TemperatureBIT(server, seatProvider, bridge))
```

So to test the logic I emit the BitEvent. I'm seeing the code always go to the handler of the IOException.

**EDIT 2**

Taking advice from the comments I just placed the method in another class and was able to mock the return value since that class wasn't being spied on. I'm still curious as to why the previous implementation breaks what the documentation says should happen though. Would love to know what's going on.

Comment: Post a complete minimal test.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer. A alternative design employing IoC, in which you pass your inputStream into either your `readCurrentTemperature` or the into the enclosing object, would help since you could pass a stream that contains 40. That would also allow you to avoid mocking, which isn't really for this sort of thing (strictly, mocking should be used for testing that a contract in implemented in a specific way, rather than replacing one implementation with another as in this code).